# Repository and two context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Im using Repository pattern, so I have a generic repository and two other repositories for each domain model.

[image]
[image]

I have two controllers; `productController` and `categoryController`.
Actually, in `categoryController` I make categories then in the `productController`, I assign each category to the desired product. Because of that, I have to use both repositories in my `productController`.

[image]

**My problem** is that I have two ObjectContext objects. When I want to update my product with new categories I get this error:

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because
>   they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

[image]
[image]

**How can I solve this?**

**How can I enhance my code to prevent this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be injecting your ObjectContext into your repository instances, this way you can inject the same instance into both repositories and avoid the error.

If you are using an IoC container it should allow you to specify the scope of instances it creates. If you are using Autofac, you would want to use InstancePerRequest